# Three.js Video as a Texture - Texture Distortion

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, html5-video

First off feel free to see the example here: http://alvarenga.co/threejs/index-2.html

Basically in this project, I have two cylinder's, one the outer (an image texture) and the inner (with a video texture)...After creating the second cylinder and adding it to the scene, I've applied a video as a MeshBasicMaterial.

**Creating Video**

```
            // create the video element
            video = document.createElement( 'video' );
            video.src = "scene-4-death-loop.mp4";
            video.load(); // must call after setting/changing source
            video.play();           

            videoImage = document.createElement( 'canvas' );
            videoImage.width = 600;
            videoImage.height = 430;

            videoImageContext = videoImage.getContext( '2d' );
            
            // background color if no video present
            videoImageContext.fillStyle = '#000000';
            videoImageContext.fillRect( 0, 0, videoImage.width, videoImage.height );

            videoTexture = new THREE.Texture( videoImage );
```

**Applying Video to Cylinder**

```
            meshVid = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.CylinderGeometry(730, 730, 500, 100, 100, true),
                      new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial ( { map: videoTexture } )) ;
```

You can see now this is fine, in the link I've posted. The video is playing as a texture on the inner cylinder. The only issue is the video is very distorted. It's being applied in a way that stretches it along the cylinder. Is there anyway to make it take up it's actual size?

I imagine this has to do with splitting the cylinder into multiple faces, and potentially applying the texture to only ONE portion--but I'm not sure how to approach that issue. Even then, this will leave the width of the video completely dependent on the width of the face.

For those curious, I want the video to be curved along the face of the cylinder, so creating a flat plane with specified sizes is not an option.

Any suggestions or guidance here?

Comment: Can you do a sketch on a drawing program of how you want the video to be mapped?

Comment: Here's a quick diagram of what I'm trying to achieve: http://i.imgur.com/4BRbZSr.jpg

Comment: See if just bending a plane works for you: http://jsfiddle.net/K5hLQ/. If you need a complete circle, you can add another geometry.

Comment: First of all, that is awesome. Get's me very close to where I need to be. I have a couple of questions regarding PlaneGeometry...You can see an example here: http://alvarenga.co/threejs/index-3.html ...one thing, you have to move left to see the plane I added. I don't see any parameters to shift the plane to the left or right, how would I position it? Another thing I've noticed is...the video seems to be getting cropped. Do you know how I could possible make the video FIT within the geometry I created? you can see the video here: alvarenga.co/threejs/scene-4-death-loop.mp4

Comment: Ended up figuring this out! I wasn't specifying the actual video width and height when I was creating a canvas element above. DERP...also positioning the new mesh was as simple as setting the position.x and rotation.y on it...thanks again for the curved plane, really awesome stuff!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try playing with `texture.repeat` and `texture.offset`.

```
videoTexture.repeat.x = 10;
videoTexture.offset.x = 0.5;
```

Comment: So I played around with them. repeat, determines how many times the texture is repeated, so I set it to 1. I've updated the test: http://alvarenga.co/threejs/index-2.html

The offet should determine the distance from where the texture gets rendered.

It still seems weird though. There's a lot of weird blurry distortion because of the offset. Another thing I've noticed, three.js seems to be changing the aspect ratio of my video in order to fit it...you can see the actual video here: http://alvarenga.co/threejs/scene-4-death-loop.mp4 ...basically  I want to render that whole video at actual size